# Is Network.Socket programming in Haskell "Concurrently, Asynchronously, Parallel, Non-Blocking" using forkIO

Tags: multithreading, sockets, haskell

Please I want to understand that whether GHC's RTS handles blocking Read/Write operations concurrently, i.e. lets say my hypothetical server can only handle CPU 1000 threads parallel,  if all 1000 forkIO are blocked due to Persistent Client socket blocking Read/Write and there are another 500 requests to be processed.

Option-A> Does the another 500 request have to wait until the 1000 forkIO process is done.

Option-B> Haskell internally handles (i.e. Concurrently, Asynchronously, Parallel, Non-Blocking) 1000 + 500 forkIO, by efficiently using all 1000 CPU threads.

Just for info I have read many socket tutorials(and blogs) for both C and Haskell(Network.Socket), to have the understanding of how Haskell(forkIO) and C handles (i.e. Concurrently, Asynchronously, Parallel, Non-Blocking), but I don't have a clear understanding of how Haskell does that actually.

Reference :

https://github.com/lpeterse/haskell-socket/issues/15#issuecomment-224382491

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `forkIO` spawns a green thread, not an O/S thread, so if you spawn 1000 `forkIO` threads to handle simultaneous requests, that does not correspond to 1000 separate O/S (or "CPU") threads.

Anyway, yes, the RTS handles multiple blocking read/write calls concurrently without tying up O/S threads.  In fact, by default when you compile and run a Haskell program without the `-threaded` flag or without the `-N` RTS option, it runs everything in a **single** O/S thread, even things you "fork" with `forkIO`, and multiple green threads can still block without blocking the (only) O/S thread.

You would also never run a Haskell server on 1000 separate O/S threads.  The RTS can schedule thousands of green threads on a small pool of O/S threads much more efficiently than running each green thread on its own O/S thread, because switching between green threads doesn't require an expensive O/S context switch.

You may find [this 2012 article about the Warp web server library](http://www.aosabook.org/en/posa/warp.html) helpful.  In particular, they compare and contrast multiple possible architectures: one CPU thread per request (i.e., the design you're imagining), an event-driven architecture, a hybrid with one event-handling process per core, and the Haskell model of lightweight threads running on an O/S thread pool.  Note that Warp uses `Network.Socket` under the hood.  In their benchmark setup, they were handling requests for 1000 simultaneous clients using anywhere from 1-10 O/S threads.

If you'd like some concrete proof that `forkIO` threads won't block, here's a toy program:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Concurrent
import Network.Socket hiding (recv)
import Network.Socket.ByteString
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS

forks = 10

main = withSocketsDo $ do
  s <- socket AF_INET Datagram defaultProtocol
  bind s (SockAddrInet 6667 (tupleToHostAddress (127,0,0,1)))
  replicateM_ forks $ forkIO (BS.putStrLn =<< recv s 4096)
  let loop = (putStrLn =<< getLine) >> loop
  loop
```

If you compile and run this without threading:

```
$ stack ghc -- -O2 Socket.hs && ./Socket
```

it will spawn 10 waiting `forkIO` threads and then enter a `getLine`/`putStrLn` loop that will echo your input back to you.    In the meantime, you can use netcat or your favorite networking tool to send requests to the waiting threads:

```
$ echo -n 'request' | nc -uw0 localhost 6667
```

which will also be echoed by the server.  After 10 requests, you will have exhausted the waiting threads, and it will no longer respond to network requests.

Then you can bump up the threads with `fork = 10000` to create 10000 waiting threads.  While they're waiting, the main `getLine`/`putStrLn` loop will continue to run without a glitch.

All this is happening within a single O/S thread, as you can verify by looking at `ps -Lf` or whatever.

The question arose in a comment whether more threads were needed if multiple sockets are used simultaneously and the program is compiled with `-threaded`.  The following test program:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Concurrent
import Network.Socket hiding (recv)
import Network.Socket.ByteString
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS

forks = 50

main = withSocketsDo $ do
  forM_ [0..forks-1] $ \i -> forkIO $ do
    s <- socket AF_INET Datagram defaultProtocol
    bind s (SockAddrInet (6667+i) (tupleToHostAddress (127,0,0,1)))
    BS.putStrLn =<< recv s 4096
  let loop = (putStrLn =<< getLine) >> loop
  loop
```

creates 50 separate sockets on ports 6667 to 6716 and waits on them.  If compiled without threading, it runs in one O/S thread without difficulty.  If compiled with threading and provided with a capability count above one, like so:

```
$ stack ghc -- -O2 -threaded Socket.hs
$ ./Socket +RTS -N4
```

it appears to run 11 worker threads (which I think is a "main thread", four capabilities, plus six spare worker threads as specified by the constant `MAX_SPARE_WORKERS` in the RTS source) which share waiting on those 50 sockets.

As an aside, the way this is accomplished in the `Network.Socket` code is that a `recv` call, for example, is ultimately implemented as:

```
throwSocketErrorWaitRead sock "..." $
    c_recv s (castPtr ptr) (fromIntegral nbytes) 0
```

with the `throwSocketErrorWaitRead` wrapper defined as:

```
throwSocketErrorWaitRead :: (Eq a, Num a) => 
     Socket -> String -> IO a -> IO a
throwSocketErrorWaitRead sock name io =
    throwSocketErrorIfMinus1RetryMayBlock name
        (threadWaitRead $ fromIntegral $ fdSocket sock)
        io
```

and `throwSocketErrorIfMinus1RetryMayBlock` documented like so:

```
throwSocketErrorIfMinus1RetryMayBlock
    :: (Eq a, Num a)
    => String  -- ^ textual description of the location
    -> IO b    -- ^ action to execute before retrying if an
               --   immediate retry would block
    -> IO a    -- ^ the 'IO' operation to be executed
    -> IO a
```

It's all a little complicated, but the upshot is that the wrappers call `c_recv` with is the actual `recv` system call.  It never blocks because the socket is configured as non-blocking, and if it returns with an error code indicating it *would* block, the `threadWaitRead` call is used to alert the RTS that this green thread should sleep until data is available for reading.

Comment: I don't think you're being careful enough here. `Network.Socket` only allows one OS thread to handle each socket, as I understand it. It does *not* do the sort of special handling the GHC I/O subsystem does to make believe that multiple threads can do so concurrently. So you need one bound thread (created with `forkOS`, `forkOn`, `asyncBound`, `asyncOn`, etc.) to manage each socket on behalf of other threads.

Comment: I don't think that's right -- I can modify the program to open 10 different sockets on 10 different ports, and it works much the same -- everything runs in one O/S thread which never forks and spends most of its time waiting on a `select` call for `stdin` and the 10 sockets.

Comment: Oh, because you compile it to run without threading. But that doesn't seem like a good idea if this is part of a larger program that needs threading! Better, I think, to write the code so it will work in that context too.

Comment: Even if it's compiled with `-threaded` and `+RTS -N4`, it's *still* the case that there's no one-O/S-thread-per-socket rule.  The RTS will start up more than 4 O/S threads in a pool, but the number is still capped.  If I open 50 sockets, I get 11 O/S threads.  I believe the excess is determined by the `MAX_SPARE_WORKERS` constant in the RTS source which allows a certain number of O/S threads over the capability count.  Anyway, I've added the source to the answer.

Comment: It sounds like we might be talking past each other, unless I'm just missing something. The [Haddocks](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-2.8.0.0/docs/Network-Socket.html) have a note: "The proper programming model is that one `Socket` is handled by a single thread. If multiple threads use one `Socket` concurrently, unexpected things would happen. There is one exception for multiple threads vs a single `Socket`: one thread reads data from a `Socket` only and the other thread writes data to the `Socket` only."

Comment: Here you create ten green threads (which could actually run on more than one OS thread), each of which attempts to read from the `Socket`. That violates the rule, which is based on a similar one for the underlying C interface. You have to make sure that for each `Socket`, only one thread reads from it and only one thread writes to it.

Comment: I believe that refers to the issue noted further down where reuse of a closed FD can cause problems.  So, it's probably a bad idea to handle a single socket with multiple green threads, particularly if any of them try to close it, but there's no requirement that there be one active O/S thread for each socket.

Comment: Oh, certainly not. There just needs to be *at most* one. But I believe the underlying C interface is a bit pickier. Specifically, I think you need to make sure that only one OS thread reads/writes to a particular socket, meaning that the thread doing so must be *bound* so it can't migrate from one OS thread to another.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180481/discussion-between-k-a-buhr-and-dfeuer).